# how to use array in any() function?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can run a statement like

select 'a' like any('a',b'), but is it still possible to run this statement if ('a','b') were in an array?

select 'a' like any(array_construct('a','b')) doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript UDF to approximate this behavior. Rather than trying to get JavaScript to simulate the like syntax, it's probably better to use richer, more expressive Regular Expressions. This UDF will return `true` if any array member matches that regexp pattern, `false` if none do, and `null` if the regex pattern is invalid or it encounters an unexpected error:

```
create or replace function LIKE_ANY_ARRAY("arr" array, "pattern" string)
returns boolean
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
"option strict"
try {
    var regex = RegExp(pattern,"g")
    for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if(regex.test(arr[i])) return true;
    }
    return false;
} catch {
    return null;
}
$$;

select like_any_array(array_construct('a','b'), 'a');            -- True
select like_any_array(array_construct('abcde','b'), '[a-z]{5}'); -- True
select like_any_array(array_construct('abcde','b'), '[a-z]{8}'); -- False, none have enough letters
select like_any_array(array_construct(2,'b'), '[a-z]{8}');       -- Auto-casting
select like_any_array(array_construct('a', 'b'), '[');           -- Invalid regex pattern returns NULL
```

This is returning a Boolean to approximate the behavior of the `LIKE ANY` function, but could very easily be converted to returning an array of all the matching members or an integer representing the first match, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn you array into a string that resembles a regex and match against that

```
where 'a' rlike array_to_string( ['a','b'],'|')
```